# Haskell Multi-line Lambdas

Tags: haskell, lambda, multiline, parse-error

I am learning Haskell from learnyouahaskell.com and there is an example such that:

```
search :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool  
search needle haystack =   
    let nlen = length needle  
    in  foldl (\acc x -
> if take nlen x == needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```

But when tried this code with GHC, it gives me

```
error: parse error on input ‘-’
```

But it works when it is like this:

```
search :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool  
search needle haystack =   
    let nlen = length needle  
    in  foldl (\acc x -> if take nlen x == needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```

Is there a feature of Haskell that allows multi-line lambdas or is that something I am missing?

Comment: You are allowed multi line lambdas. However you're splitting the line at the worst possible place. The `->` is important! keep that and it should work.

Comment: just don't break your arrow - keep it together `\acc x ->` and indent the next line

Comment: You can't insert a linebreak in the middle of words or operators.

Comment: Keeping together the `->` operator and indenting the next line solved the problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: Could someone post an answer so I mark it as answered, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't break the `->`

Just do:

```
search :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool  
search needle haystack =   
   let nlen = length needle  
   in  foldl (\acc x ->
if take nlen x == needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```

or

```
search :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool  
search needle haystack =   
   let nlen = length needle  
   in  foldl (\acc x 
-> if take nlen x == needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```