# How to get a multiline lambda working when lambda is a function argument?

Tags: haskell

I have some code as follows, that, when all on one line, compiles and functions correctly:

```
let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
  -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
```

But the error I'm getting currently is:

```
Main.hs:31:7: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
31 |       -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
   |       ^
```

I saw [Haskell Multi-line Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673518/haskell-multi-line-lambdas) but maybe I'm missing something still, or maybe this is just a different issue.

Stylistic suggestions that go beyond what is needed to just get this working are also welcome.

**Update:** Both @melpomene and Chris Smith's answers address this question, and are worth reading (for others seeing this)! For stylistic improvements, someone also suggested using `$` like which I appreciate, but their answer was deleted (I presume because the core issue was not addressed - but thank you as well):

```
let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) $ \(x :. y)
      -> noiseValue perlinNoise (fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 )
```

Comment: If it is necessary to try this out, I just have the following imports:  `Prelude hiding (map)`, `Data.Massiv.Array as MA`, and `mapSize :: Int`.

Comment: if you always use explicit brackets (`let { a=x; b=y } in ...` etc.), you will never have these kind of silly problems (also, tabs mixed with spaces, etc). I know it's unpopular, and I can't understand why. It works.

Comment: @WillNess I have to admit, I am somewhat inclined to do so. Partly because whitespace (at least in python) can at times cause surprising behavior, partly because it is more explicitly obvious with `{ }`, and partly because the editor I'm using at the moment (`acme`) seems to make it particularly difficult to notice exact alignment, but that's probably my bad.

Comment: one doesn't contradict the other. of course we should have nice consistent  indentation, but with the explicit delimiters we also get correctness guarantee -- and sometimes / oftentimes it even makes the code *clearer* (like with e.g. multi-line expressions), which should always be our goal. all at a "price" of just a few extra keystrokes. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax of `let` is

```
let { DECLARATIONS } in EXPRESSION
```

or (in a `do` block)

```
let { DECLARATIONS } ;
```

You almost never see the `{` `}` used in code because they're usually implicit: The token after `let` (if it's not a `{`) determines the base indentation of the following block of declarations. New lines that are indented more than the base indentation are left unchanged; new lines that have the same indentation as the base indentation get an implicit `;` inserted before them; new line with less indentation terminate the block. This whitespace sensitive syntax is called "layout".

In

```
--      v
    let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
      -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
--    ^
```

the first token after `let` is `xsMat` (marked with `v`). This is the start of an implicit block.

The following line is less indented than the base indentation (marked `^`). This implicitly terminates the block, so the parser sees

```
let { xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y)
  } -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
```

and gets confused because the `\` inside the block is not terminated and the `->` outside of the block makes no sense either.

Solution:

```
let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
     -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
```

Indent the `-> ...` line more than `xsMat`. That way it's read as a continuation line and the whole thing parses as

```
let { xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
       -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) ) }
```

Alternatively you can also write

```
let { xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
  -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) ) }
```

by hand. If you use `{`, layout mode doesn't kick in and you can format everything pretty much any way you want.

Answer (score 5):

You are running into problems with layout in the `let` statement.  The first non-whitespace character after `let` sets a new layout level.  Any future lines indented *more* than that are interpreted as continuing the definition on their previous line.  Any lines indented *equal* to that are interpreted as starting a new definition in the `let` block.  Any lines indented *less* than that are considered to come *after* the `let` block.

So you can't write this:

```
let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
  -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
```

But you can write this:

```
let xsMat = makeArrayR U Seq(mapSize :. mapSize) (\(x :. y) 
            -> noiseValue perlinNoise(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 ) )
```

The only difference is that the continued line is indented further than `xsMat`.